# document.write in jsonp callback

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events, cross-domain

I am making a cross domain request using script tag hack and jsonp. In the callback function, I want to write the data received to DOM using `document.write()`.

I know that I should use appendChild/innerHTML instead of `doc.write()`. My constraint is I do not have a class/id hook to the element I want to write to. I can only rely on `document.write()` to write "in place".

Following code is included in HTML div in a script tag.:

```
function request_jsonp(){
var script = document.createElement('script');
var server_path = 'http://somedomain.com/?q=querystring&callback=request_callback';
script.setAttribute('src', server_path);
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
console.log('data requested');
// document.write('hello world'); // this gets written
}


function request_callback(data){
    console.log('data received');
    document.write(data);
}


 request_jsonp();

 window.onload = function(){
     console.log('onload fired');
 }


/* 
above code prints

data requested
data received
onload fired
*/
```

Basically `document.write` does not work even with a static string inside the callback function. I thought that if `document.write` is called before `onload`, it inserts text in the page as noted [here JavaScript and HTML Script Tags](http://javascript.crockford.com/script.html)

What is preventing the `document.write()` to write to DOM? Also, is there a better approach to do this?

Comment: "I do not have a class/id hook to the element I want to write to." -- then send it via GET param of jsonp.

Comment: I think I did not make myself clear. To send it via GET, an id/class needs to be present on the element in first place.

Comment: You may use just an index among all other elements like: `Array.prototype.indexOf.call(document.getElementsByTagName('*'), element)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should note that `document.write();` calls an implicit `document.open();`, thus, in effect, clearing everything you have had in the document so far.
It is impossible to *add* content to a document using `document.write();`. It is, however, possible to use `document.write();` to write an entire document.

You have several possible solutions:

- You can pass the target element as a GET parameter, as @kirilloid noted.
- You can insert an IFrame object at the desired place, and use `myIFrame.document.write();` to update its content.

This is basically happening because you are updating the content of a container that is the parent to your script code, and as such, is not closed yet.

Either that, or I'm entirely off track here which, let's face it, is entirely possible. ;-)

Comment: "You can insert an IFrame object at the desired place" How do I do this? I do not have an id/class hook to the parent div in which I need to insert iframe. Basically I want to say this.parentNode.appendChild(myIFrame)

Comment: You are right. That couldn't work, without knowing the target element. You can always include the code for `document.write();` in your included script file.
That way, the writing block won't be executed until after the container is closed.

Comment: It should also be noted that your callback function resides on the client side of the JSONP pattern, and as such should be aware of the specifics of the page you are creating via JSONP. If not, you should revise your design.