# JSONP with document.write

Tags: jsonp, document.write

I'am loading a script jspnp-like

```
var s = document.createElement("script");
s.src = "http://scripturl";
s.type = "text/javascript";
document.getElementById("ad").appendChild(s);
```

when the script contains an alert it just works. But the real script needs to "document.write". But the document.write is never output. Any ideas why? The script console does not show any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is is similar to the questions found

http://www.webmasterworld.com/javascript/4401935.htm
and

[document.write in jsonp callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8656509/document-write-in-jsonp-callback)

It seems that calling document.write() is calling document.open(), which erases everything you previously have written. By the time the document.write() is executed, the page has already finished loading.

Take a look at the solutions provided in the links above and try modifying them for your specific needs. Try using an iframe and write to that.

Comment: hm the solution with an iframe is ugly but works... in firefox ... opera ... chrome... safai... but noch IE11! =( he just crashes